# Filtering linux kernel event tracing

Tags: linux-kernel, trace

I want to debug a linux kernel tcp issue. For this am planning to enable to following tcp events tracing as follows:-

> echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/tcp/tcp_retransmit_skb/enable
>
> echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/tcp/tcp_probe/enable

However, i guess tcp_probe events would be too much in my system, so i want to filter the tcp_probe events. I'm able to filter using dest and source port numbers as follows:-

> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/tcp/tcp_probe# echo "dport == 179" > filter

But, am not able to filter using ip address, i get below error upon trying:-

> echo "daddr == "172.18.9.46"" > filter
>
> write error: Operation not permitted

Can someone please help with an example on how to filter based on ip addresses.

Comment: In the last the quoting seems ambiguous, have you tried to change outer double quotes by single ones?

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses need to be an integer.  I think you probably want something like:

```
echo "daddr == 0xac12092e" > filter
```

or

```
echo "daddr == 0xac12092e && dport == 179" > filter
```